# When should you, and when should you not, use wp_list_pluck()?

Tags: functions, customization

While learning about metadata lazy-loading, I met [these lines of code](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5/src/wp-includes/comment.php#L478):

```
// Don't use `wp_list_pluck()` to avoid by-reference manipulation.
$comment_ids = array();
if ( is_array( $comments ) ) {
    foreach ( $comments as $comment ) {
        if ( $comment instanceof WP_Comment ) {
            $comment_ids[] = $comment->comment_ID;
        }
    }
}
```

I thought it relates to [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307409/php-pass-by-reference-in-foreach) but there're no references here and the only `foreach` loop is wrapped inside a function, how by-reference manipulation can happen in this case?

And, for best practice, when should we use `wp_list_pluck()` function?

Comment: I'm with you, fwiw. I've looked at the function source, codex & dev docs and can't see what that comment refers to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In any `foreach` loop, the last value of the array being looped over remains after the end of the `foreach` loop. That is why one should actually always unset that value after the `foreach` loop is done.

[`wp_list_pluck()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_pluck/) is also just a basic `foreach` loop if `$index_key` is not passed. Also, as with any `foreach` loop, the last value of the array remains after the end of the `foreach` loop, and I think this is what that line refers to in the codex.

However, that assumption is wrong. [Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.functions.php) are self contained pieces of code, and except for globals, these pieces of code inside a function are only avaiable to the function itself. `wp_list_pluck()` does not globalize any of its intenal values (*variables*), so even if the last value of the array is still available after the `foreach` loop inside the function, and does not get unset, it is not available to any piece of code outside the function, so you cannot have the pass-by-reference issue as described in that line in the codex.

`wp_list_pluck()` is as valid to use as any simple `foreach` loop. The choice is up to you. I personally prefer `wp_list_pluck()` as it saves on code, and you do not need to remember to unset variables which can later lead to debugging nightmare.

Just a final note, `wp_list_pluck()` can also replace `array_column` as it works the same if `$index_key` is passed to the function

Comment: Unset or reset?

Comment: @toscho AFAIK and from what I have learned, `unset( $value )` after a `foreach` loop,  `wp_reset_postdata()` if you used `setup_postdata( $post )` in a `foreach` loop, and `reset()`  sets the internal pointer back to the first item in an array. If I'm wrong, or if you have anything else or different to add, you should do that in an answer so that we all benefit from that. IMHO, this is a question that most of the community can benefit from, and if I'm wrong, correct me then and post a proper answer